# How can GNOME Files(Nautilus) use the default settings for mounting NTFS disks with NTFS3 kernel module? Replacement of NTFS-3G and FUSE

Tags: 20.04, kernel, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Two virtual machines are installed on the host with Ubuntu 18.04 and VMware Workstation Player: Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Windows 11(the "quick start" function is disabled `powercfg /h off`).

```
Installing Kernel 5.15.1 with Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer
https://github.com/bkw777/mainline
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

sudo su started in the terminal

```
mainline --help
mainline --check 
mainline --list-installed
mainline --install-latest
```

Downloaded and installed

```
linux-headers-5.15.1-051501-generic_5.15.1-051501.202111061036_amd64.deb
linux-headers-5.15.1-051501_5.15.1-051501.202111061036_all.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.15.1-051501-generic_5.15.1-051501.202111061036_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.15.1-051501-generic_5.15.1-051501.202111061036_amd64.deb
```

I connected the NVMe Windows 11 disk to Ubuntu. Rebooting Ubuntu Server 20.04.

```
sudo su started in the terminal
uname -r
5.15.1-051501-generic
modinfo ntfs3
```

[image: ntfs3]

```
mkdir /media/c_win11
lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID
```

ntfs3 mount options

```
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ntfs3.html
```

Next

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab_backup
sudo echo 'UUID=6A9C72639C7229A9 /media/c_win11 ntfs3 iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Next, it is necessary to provide the user with write access to the directory in which the partition is mounted:

```
sudo chown user /media/c_win11
```

I can create packages, edit files and documents with the rights of a regular user on a partition with Windows 11.

Installed GNOME Shell

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

[image: ntfs3]

The auto-mounting of the Windows 11 disk is also saved in Nautilus. This is not always convenient. Sometimes it is necessary to temporarily mount NTFS disks in Nautilus.

**Question:**

How can GNOME Files(Nautilus) use the default settings for mounting NTFS disks with NTFS3 kernel module? Replacement of NTFS-3G and FUSE.

**Warning!!!** [MainlineBuilds.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) The mainline kernel builds are produced for debugging purposes and therefore come with no support. Use them at your own risk.

Kernel Uninstall: sudo su started in the terminal (then all commands in the terminal with root rights)

```
mainline --list-installed
mainline --uninstall 5.15.1
```

Comment: Is there an actual problem here? This site isn't for polls, so simply asking if someone has done X isn't really a valid question. This seems like a guide. If that's the case, post the problem you're trying to solve in the question and the solution as an answer.

Comment: "Has anyone configured the ntfs3 driver" I hope not. The driver became obsolete and has become a kernel module. I agree with muru: nothing for us to answer? besides a yes/no...

Comment: Thank you for your opinion and response. I tested the support for reading and writing the NTFS3 kernel module by Paragon Software and wanted to clarify the mount parameters in Caja, Nautilus, Dolphin using NTFS3. The option with ntfs-3g and fuseblk in recent years is enough for me.

Comment: @Rinzwind: No, that's wrong. The driver is the Paragon driver which was recently given to the official kernel by Paragon and is used from 5.15 on. It obsoletes not only the old kernel `ntfs` module, but also `ntfs-3g`. The answer given is the proper way to use the new `ntfs3` for people with an urgent need to run a performant ntfs driver under Ubuntu. Official from 22.04 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

Configuring mounting with NTFS3 kernel module by Paragon Software in the Nautilus file manager. I have read the information on the links: [Configurable mount options](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) ,
[storaged-project](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/798) , [ntfs3-dkms](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ntfs3-dkms/?O=140&PP=10)

A virtual machine with Ubuntu 21.10 Gnome and Windows 11 is installed in dual boot.

Installing Kernel 5.15.2 with Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer.

sudo su started in the terminal (then all commands in the terminal with root rights):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
apt update
apt install mainline
mainline --check 
mainline --list-installed
mainline --install-latest
```

Rebooting Ubuntu.

sudo su started in the terminal (then all commands in the terminal with root rights):

```
uname -r
5.15.2-051502-generic
modinfo ntfs3
```

Launch nautilus and mount a disk with Windows 11.

```
mount | grep nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /media/user/6A9C72639C7229A9 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

In nautilus unmount drive with Windows 11.

Creating a rule for udev in the terminal:

```
sudo dd status=none of=/etc/udev/rules.d/99-ntfs3.rules <<EOF
# UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
# ==1: mount filesystem to a shared directory (/media/VolumeName)
# ==0: mount filesystem to a private directory (/run/media/$USER/VolumeName)
# See udisks(8)
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="ntfs", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}="ntfs3" , ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="1"
EOF
```

Reloading udev rules without restarting Ubuntu.

```
sudo udevadm control -R
```

Launch nautilus and mount a disk with Windows 11.

```
sudo mount | grep nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on /media/6A9C72639C7229A9 type ntfs3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,iocharset=utf8,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Return the default settings (fuse and ntfs-3g) with the command:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/99-ntfs3.rules
sudo udevadm control -R ## or reboot Ubuntu.
```

Now I will test ntfs3 with Proton (Steam Play- Using-a-NTFS-disk-with-Linux-and-Windows) on a real computer.

Naturally, I will not test on the Mainline Kernel. I use a ready-made [XanMod kernel (STABLE) (5.14)](https://xanmod.org/)

Comment: From 22.04 on or with kernel 5.15, this is a very convenient way to use the new `ntfs3` module by default. ONLY the udev rule is needed to do this, no further changes. To have the full Ubuntu default behaviour, I recommend using `ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="0"` instead of 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, this is my typo, of course: ENV{UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED}="0". The other day I will test 22.04. I hope for the tradition: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on April 21, 2022